# PhantomJS Click an li without and id

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

Have an html that is populated elsewhere. It will have various li tags with text in them, but no ids. I'm looking to find a way to search the page for the li tag that contains a word and click on it using PhantomJS.

Essentially, there could be an li with "Purple (25)." That number might change on each reload, so I want to search the dom for a li containing "purple" and then click on it. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to select an element that contains the word purple. There is no contains text selector is CSS, so you will need to grab all the lis and then find/filter it out to find the purple ones.

If there is just one:

```
const purpleElem = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("li")) // find all the lis
                     .find(li =>   // locate the element that has the match
                       li.textContent.contains('Purple') // see if it has purple
                     )
```

If there are more than one

```
const purpleElems = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("li")) // find all the lis
                     .filter(li =>   // filter the list of lis
                       li.textContent.contains('Purple') // see if it has purple
                     )
```

Comment: Could probably use `find` instead of `filter` to return one element no?

Comment: How would this work within the context of phantomJS though? How would I click it? Would I need a page.evaluate ->include your suggestion. Then page.sendevent of that evaluate?

Comment: not sure how it is different than using getElementById and calling click.